# How to embed different languages in android apps?

Tags: android

I have made an app.(base version Gingerbread 2.3) and now I want to embed different languages to it so that the user can use the app. in different languages. But the process of embedding different languages is not clear to me(I'm a new to android programming), somebody please explain it in details with code.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 1):

Multi language support is easy done for android. Create a new `values` directory for the language with the suffix of the language code. For `german: values-de` or f`rench: values-fr` than copy your `strings.xml` into that and translate each entry.

For more information refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).

Comment: Will just adding those values directory be fine?

Comment: Yes.. you need to create new folder name it values-fr and copy your string.xml to that directory. You need to only change values of string variables in string.xml

Comment: Will it change all the text in my app.? If so, then its not working.

Comment: Yes it changes all the text. I think you are not follow my steps or made some mistake in code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial to get you started: 
http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/

Essentially, you need to create individual `values` folders for all the languages you wish to support.

For example, if you are supporting French along with the default English, then, you will need to create a `values-fr` folder. If you wish to support region specific languages, then you will need to create those too. For example, French language with the Region set to Canada, then you will need to create this: `values-fr-rCA`

How this works is:
1. If the Region is set to **Canada** and the `Language` is set to **French**, the OS will look for the values folder: `values-fr-rCA`
2. If the above is not found, it looks for `values-fr`.
3. If none of the above are found, it defaults back to the normal `values` folder.

You will need to code your Strings.XML for all the values you use throughout your application. ** Hard-coded** strings will not be switch to other Languages.

The same goes for `drawables` too.

Read more about [Localization here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.

But I'm mainly facing problem in linking the string.xml with the main file. Can I get it in code form.
As I'm unable to access the codes properly from the above example.

Comment: @NewBee: Glad to have been of help. :-)

Comment: But I'm mainly facing problem in linking the string.xml with the main file. Can I get it in code form. As I'm unable to access the codes properly from the above example.

Comment: @NewBee: What do you mean by _linking the string.xml with the main file_. Did you check the example from the tutorial linked in the post?

Comment: Ya I checked that but the example is not opening in Eclipse. So I'm requesting for a complete code as I'm creating my first app.

Comment: @NewBee: It already is a complete working example (code) in the tutorial. Search SO / Google on how to import projects in eclipse. I am sure when importing projects is sorted out.